# Collect Data from File with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to collect data from a file with logstash, but it not works,this is my logstash.conf file :

```
{

input {

stdin { }

file {
type => "tomcat-access"
path => ["/Users/aymen/Desktop/Projet Big Data/outils/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/var/log/test.txt"]

}

}

filter {

grok {
  match => [ "message", "%{WORD:firstname} %{WORD:lastname} %{NUMBER:age}"]
}

}

output {
 stdout { }

elasticsearch {
cluster => "logstash"
 }
 }

}
```

and this is my data file :

```
Kevin Larsing 34
Nicolas Derel 22
Florence Niral 32
Ines Lkiel 23
```

Best regards.

Comment: what's the error message? describe the whole procedure you are doing please!

Comment: Start by removing the outermost braces. input, filter, and output should be at the top level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Magnus says, you don't need the outermost braces. Aside from that, you're probably going to want to add (at least for testing):

```
start_position => 'beginning'
```

...to the input file stream. This will ensure that existing logs in your test file are pulled in. Docs [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#start_position) - Note that the default value for this setting is "end".

My working .conf file looks like this:

```
input {
  stdin { }
  file {
    type => "tomcat-access"
    path => "/in.txt"
    start_position => 'beginning'
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{WORD:firstname} %{WORD:lastname} %{NUMBER:age}"]
  }
}
output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch {
    cluster => "henrys_elasticsearch"
  }
}
```